# Changing to Nvidia Driver Broke Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, cinnamon

When changing to the Nvidia 3.75 Driver, through the manager and restarting, I'd received a nice little message about Cinnamon Crashing and an update of "mode." I tried to restart Cinnamon through the dialogue box but it just loops and doesn't fix the problem.

What can I do about this? Google isn't turning over anything up to date for me, on this problem.

I'm running Linux Mint 18.1

If any more information is needed, please ask me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue by adding a ppa from here https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

In that site there are two lines to add to the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The purpose of the above was to add a history of drivers for Nvidia up to the most current 381 (at present). I hadn't realized that a lot of content was controlled via PPA's. Finally, I added this line into the terminal (substituting the value from an outdated forum answer for current version) and followed the prompts:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-381 nvidia-prime
```

After a brief reset, I'm able to use my Nvidia Driver as normal. The screen is fancier and games will now run up to the limits of my GPU.